# How to remove an object from an array that is nested, given only one value from that object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, socket.io

I have a `rooms` object in `socket.io` that looks like this:

```
rooms = {
    room1: {
        roomName: "room2",
        playerUrl: "",
        host: "3I07byxcFRhX6o5nAAAR",
        users: [
            { id: someId, foo: true, bar: false },
            { id: anotherId, foo: true, bar: false },
        ],
    },
    room2: {
        roomName: "room2",
        playerUrl: "",
        host: "3I07byxcFRhX6o5nAAAR",
        users: [
            { id: someId, foo: true, bar: false },
            { id: anotherId, foo: true, bar: false },
        ],
    },
```

Given `someId`, I want to remove the user with that id from the room that contains that user. I do not have the name of the room. Once I have the room name, I can do something like:

```
rooms[roomName] = {
    ...rooms[roomName],
    users: [rooms[roomName].users.filter((user) => user.id !== someId)],
};
```

My question is - how do I get the name of the room, given only the id of one of its users?

This is a `socket.io` disconnect event, making it difficult to pass down arguments. I have the `roomName` in redux store, but it's wiped when the socket disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `#Array.forEach` and `#Array.filter`

You can loop over the values of the `rooms` object using `Array#forEach` and filter out the desired users using `Array#Filter`.

```js
const rooms = {
  room1: {
    roomName: "room2",
    playerUrl: "",
    host: "3I07byxcFRhX6o5nAAAR",
    users: [
      { id: "abc", foo: true, bar: false },
      { id: "xyz", foo: true, bar: false },
    ],
  },
  room2: {
    roomName: "room2",
    playerUrl: "",
    host: "3I07byxcFRhX6o5nAAAR",
    users: [
      { id: "abc", foo: true, bar: false },
      { id: "xyz", foo: true, bar: false },
    ],
  },
};

const userId = "abc";

Object.values(rooms).forEach((o) => {
  o.users = o.users.filter(({ id }) => id !== userId);
});

console.log(rooms)
```

Comment: @relativenoob Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const findRoomsWithUser = (rooms, userid) => {
    return Object.values(rooms)
        .filter(room => room.users.some(u => u.id === userid))
        .map(room => room.roomName);
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/outworlder-csa/pen/yLgrJdg)

Answer (score 0):

**concrete data**

I added some actual user `id` values and fixed the `roomName` values. Here's the sample data I am working with -

```js
const rooms = {
  room1: {
    roomName: "room1",
    playerUrl: "",
    host: "3I07byxcFRhX6o5nAAAR",
    users: [
      { id: "abc", foo: true, bar: false },
      { id: "def", foo: true, bar: false },
    ],
  },
  room2: {
    roomName: "room2",
    playerUrl: "",
    host: "X6o5nAAAR3I07byxcFRh",
    users: [
      { id: "abc", foo: true, bar: false },
      { id: "xyz", foo: true, bar: false },
    ],
  },
};
```

**generators**

First we start by writing a `usersByRoom` generator. The advantages of generators are numerous. The caller can decide to handle each value however they see fit. And because they are pauseable/cancellable, in some scenarios a tremendous amount of work can be skipped -

```js
function* usersByRoom(rooms)
{ for (const [_, room] of Object.entries(rooms))
    for (const u of room.users)
      yield [room.roomName, u]
}
```

```js
for (const [roomName, user] of usersByRoom(rooms))
  console.log(roomName, user)
```

| `roomName` | `user` |
| --- | --- |
| room1 | `{ id: "abc", foo: true, bar: false }` |
| room1 | `{ id: "def", foo: true, bar: false }` |
| room2 | `{ id: "abc", foo: true, bar: false }` |
| room2 | `{ id: "xyz", foo: true, bar: false }` |

Next we write another generator, `roomsForUserId`, that accepts `rooms` and a user `id` to search for. Here we see that generators are also composable, meaning we can build complex generators out of simpler ones -

```js
function* roomsForUserId(rooms, id)
{ for (const [roomName, user] of usersByRoom(rooms))
    if (user.id == id)
      yield roomName
}
```

**test queries**

Querying for `abc`, we find two rooms -

```js
for (const roomName of roomsForUserId(rooms, "abc"))
  console.log(roomName)
```

| roomName |
| --- |
| room1 |
| room2 |

Querying for `xyz` we only find one room -

```js
for (const roomName of roomsForUserId(rooms, "xyz"))
  console.log(roomName)
```

| roomName |
| --- |
| room2 |

Querying for `lmo` we find zero rooms -

```js
for (const roomName of roomsForUserId(rooms, "lmo"))
  console.log(roomName)
```

| roomName |
| --- |
| *(no results)* |

**demo**

Run the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
function* usersByRoom(rooms)
{ for (const [_, room] of Object.entries(rooms))
    for (const u of room.users)
      yield [room.roomName, u]
}

function* roomsForUserId(rooms, id)
{ for (const [roomName, user] of usersByRoom(rooms))
    if (user.id == id)
      yield roomName
}

const rooms =
  { room1: { roomName: "room1", playerUrl: "", host: "3I07byxcFRhX6o5nAAAR", users: [ { id: "abc", foo: true, bar: false }, { id: "def", foo: true, bar: false }, ], }, room2: { roomName: "room2", playerUrl: "", host: "X6o5nAAAR3I07byxcFRh", users: [ { id: "abc", foo: true, bar: false }, { id: "xyz", foo: true, bar: false }, ] } }

console.log(Array.from(roomsForUserId(rooms, "abc")))
console.log(Array.from(roomsForUserId(rooms, "xyz")))
console.log(Array.from(roomsForUserId(rooms, "lmo")))
```

```js
[ "room1", "room2" ]
[ "room2" ]
[]
```